# Display options onclicking h:selectOneRadio

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a radiobutton that i would want to display several options related to it once its selected.. the options are on the relevant bean. how do i do that?

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{managePaymentModel.reportFilter.options}" layout="pageDirection" label="Select Option" disabled="#{managePaymentModel.reportPreview}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{managePaymentModel.reportOptions}" var="type" itemValue="#{type.value}" itemLabel="#{type.label}" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
</h:panelGrid>
```

```
@Override
public Map reportSelector() {
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    map.put(ManagePaymentBeanLocal.LIST_PAYMENTS_SUMMARY, "List of Payments Summary");
    map.put(ManagePaymentBeanLocal.LIST_PAYMENTS_DETAIL, "List of Payments Detail");
    return map;
}
@Override
public Map reportOptions(ReportFilter filter) {
    Map<Integer, String> option = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    // report configurations
    switch (filter.getSelect()) {
        case ManagePaymentBeanLocal.LIST_PAYMENTS_SUMMARY:
        case ManagePaymentBeanLocal.LIST_PAYMENTS_DETAIL:
            option.put(ReportFilter.OPTION1, "By Beneficiary");
            option.put(ReportFilter.OPTION2, "By Reference");
            break;
    }
    return option;
}
```

Comment: can you please state your problem

Comment: sorry.. just edited the question.

Comment: I have still no idea what you're concretely asking. What's the functional requirement?

Comment: sorry i am having problems phrasing the question.. thing is, i have two radio buttons on my xhtml that display "List of Payments Summary"
and "List of Payments Detail" i would like it when someone clicks on the second option i.e. "List of Payments Detail" two more options i.e. "By Beneficiary" and "By Reference" to appear..

Answer (score 0):

you can put this code inside your selectOneRadio

```
<f:ajax event="change" render="@form" />
```

this will update the model behind and rerender the formulary